Mongo DB Nested Array Updates & create in single mongo command
I have a nested mongo array
{
  "_id": 1,
  "date": "2024-09-30",
  "employees": [
    {
      "_id": 101,
      "name": "John Doe",
      "company": "ABC Corp",
      "department": "HR",
      "salary": 50000,
      "contactNumber": "123-456-7890"
    },
    {
      "_id": 102,
      "name": "A",
      "company": "XYZ Corp",
      "department": "HR",
      "salary": 500100,
      "contactNumber": "1333-456-7890"
    },
    {
      "_id": 103,
      "name": "B",
      "company": "XYZ Corp",
      "department": "HR",
      "salary": 500100,
      "contactNumber": "1333-456-7890"
    }
  ]
}



I need to update the salary of 101 and also add new memeber 104. How can i do in single update?
I am able to do with 2 updates. One to update 101's salary using ArrayFilters and another is to $push 104 to array. Below are the queries,
db.collection.updateOne(
  { _id: 1 },  // Match the document with _id: 1
  {
    $set: { "employees.$[emp].salary": 60000 }  // Set the new salary for employee with _id: 101
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [ { "emp._id": 101 } ]  // Array filter to target the specific employee with _id: 101
  }
)
db.collection.updateOne(
  { _id: 1 },  // Match the document with _id: 1
  {
    $push: {
      employees: {
        _id: 104,
        name: "New Employee",
        company: "New Corp",
        department: "HR",
        salary: 70000,
        contactNumber: "987-654-3210"
      }
    }
  }
)

Is there any way I can do both adding new employee and updating existing employee in same query.?
I think I can use aggregate to do so. but which is better in case of performance?

If the rationale behind avoiding 2 separate operation is to save the number of db calls, you may find bulk operation useful

You can do the following in an update with aggregation pipeline.

$map to iterate through the array. Conditionally update the array entry with $mergeObjects if the entry's id match your update cases(i.e. id =101 or 102) in a $switch
$concatArrays to append your new employee entry there

db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "employees": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$employees",
          "as": "e",
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$eq": [
                      101,
                      "$$e._id"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$e",
                      {
                        "salary": 60000
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$eq": [
                      102,
                      "$$e._id"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "$mergeObjects": [
                      "$$e",
                      {
                        "salary": 70000
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              "default": "$$e"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "employees": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$employees",
          [
            // new employee to insert here
            {
              _id: 104,
              name: "New Employee",
              company: "New Corp",
              department: "HR",
              salary: 70000,
              contactNumber: "987-654-3210"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

Two minor changes I would recommend: 1. Since we can have multiple stages easily, it's clearer to add the new employee in a separate stage; and unlikely to have an negative performance impact. 2. Since you're iterating over the emps array for the salary update, in theory adding the employee and then doing the map adds more items to :P But that's a very very minor (immeasurable) perf impact. 7 items vs 6 items or 50 items vs 51 items changes nothing.

Thanks for the solution and playground. with this i am able to update single id value & add new employee. but can i also update more than one employees like id=101, salary = 60000 and id=102, salary=70000 in same way & add new employee as well?.

@Banupriya updated the answer according to the comments. But I wonder if it is suitable to blend such a tailor-made logic into the same operation. You may want to check aneroid's answer for the considerations and see if you should break your updates into different operations.

This can't be be in a single update query - "Updating the path 'employees' would create a conflict at 'employees'" - which happens because both operations are on the 'employees' field. However, if you were pushing to a different field like newEmployees, then it would work. The only difference in those two linked queries is the field for $push.
Anyway, wrt to doing both together with an aggregation, one agg would be faster than two separate updates but probably not worth the complexity. Does a new employee need to be added every time another employee's salary changes?
If you need "both work or both fail" behaviour, then consider using transactions.

I think this answer is insightful in explaining the underlying behaviour and considering the actual use case and potential trade-offs.

And I think your answer is way better, especially since it does what the OP asked
